# Problema com Notices, object PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, pdo

Tenho minha classe:

```
public function SQL($sql, $arrayParams = null, $fetchAll = TRUE)
{
    try {
        // Passa a instrução para o PDO
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        // Verifica se existem condições para carregar os parâmetros
        if (!empty($arrayParams)){
            // Loop para passar os dados como parâmetro cláusula WHERE
            $cont = 1;
            foreach ($arrayParams as $valor){
                $stm->bindValue($cont, $valor);
                $cont++;
            }
        }
        // Executa a instrução SQL
        $stm->execute();
        // Verifica se é necessário retornar várias linhas
        if ($fetchAll){
            $dados = $stm->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }else{
            $dados = $stm->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        $this->nRows = count($dados);
        return $dados;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Em outra classe estou usando da seguinte maneira:

```
$db = Conexao::getInstance();
$pdo = Base::getInstance($db, "pre_cadastro");

$sql  = "SELECT nome, token FROM pre_cadastro WHERE email = ?";
$res = $pdo->SQL($sql, array('email@email.com'), false);
$nome = $res->nome; //linha 83
$token = $res->token; //linha 84
echo $nome."<br>";
echo $token;
```

Como eu uso isso para em um ajax, ta me retornando esse erro:

> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\class\SendMail.php on line 83
>   
> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\class\SendMail.php on line 84

Linha 83) `$nome = $res->nome;`

Linha 84) `$token = $res->token;`

Eu sei que são notices, mas estão me retornando esse erro no AJAX. E realmente não estão imprimindo nada..

Comment: Quais são as linhas 83 e 84 da classe SendMail.php?

Comment: Editei la.. havia esquecido de deixar explicito

Comment: A consulta pode ter retornada vazia.

Comment: Você poderia dá um `var_dump($res);` e verificar o resultado?